# Use awk and/or grep to search for individual lines based on predefined values, and then see if the following line has matching values

Tags: awk, grep

So let's say I'm given the following lines

```
[duration] =>  92
[from] => 18884541236
[to] => 17841234568
```

What I want to be able to do is search the entire file to see any instances where the [from] number is the same as the [to] number.

So if I have an entry that looks like this

```
[duration] => 43
[from] =>  17873332222
[to] => 17873332222
```

I can search the file for where the [from] number is immediately followed in the next line by an identical [to] number.

Comment: Are you only interested in consecutive cases? What if the 1st entry matches the 12th entry? Should we look for those as well?

Comment: @terdon only consecutive cases

Answer (score 0):

This command will print the line number and the contents of any lines whose first field is `[to]` and whose third field is the same as the most recently seen `[from]` value:

```
awk '{ if($1=="[from]"){from=$3} } $1=="[to]" && $3==from{print NR,$0}' file
```

Taking this file as input:

```
[duration] =>  92
[from] => 18884541236
[to] => 17841234568
[duration] => 43
[from] =>  17873332222
[to] => 17873332222
```

You get this output:

```
$ awk '{ if($1=="[from]"){from=$3} } $1=="[to]" && $3==from{print NR,$0}' file 
6 [to] => 17873332222
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working

Comment: @RyanMcMillan I can't help if you don't tell me how it is failing. Do you get an error message? No results? Wrong results? Please [edit] your question and show us an example file we can test on, and the output you expect from that example.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the sample (dangerous I know)

If `[duration]` is never going to be equal to `[from]` and `[to]` always follows immediately, then this could be as simple as...

```
awk '$3==last{ print NR, $0} {last=$3}' file
```